# Solving a non-linear integral equation in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, integral, nonlinear-functions

I'm trying to implement a Python code for solving for`F(x)`in the following integral equation:
`F(x)=0.5*int((1/sqrt(y**2+F(y)**2))((x*F(y)-y*F(x))/x)(1/abs(x-y)**     (1/3)),y,-20,20)`

All the methods that I know for solving integral equations do not work since in this case I don't have a well defined kernel due to the nonlinear term inside the square root, so I'm at a loss in how to attack this specific problem.

Comment: what do you mean by solving?

Comment: I'm trying to generate a plot of the function F(x)

Comment: what does F(y) mean?

Comment: It's the same function as F(x) but evaluated in y, which is the variable being integrated over, maybe an iterative method could be useful?

Comment: then you can replace the occurrences of y with F(x)

Comment: No, I cannot do that

Comment: I'm afraid you need to go to the literature first to figure out how to solve these sorts of equations ( a quick search on *nonlinear Fredholm equations* gives several papers), and only then it's about profeamming it python or other progeamming language. Consider asking on scicomp.stackexchange too.